# Override css classes in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need to customize the css of some React classes. In this case my aim is to display an input in a form with this css (a straight line without background):

```
.text-line {
background-color: transparent;
color: #eeeeee;
outline: none;
outline-style: none;
border-top: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

I've tried either with adding inline css or with creating custom classes but nothing seem to work.

```
<Form>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Phone number, email or username</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} value={this.state.username} />
    </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

Is there a way to clean override react default css classes? I've also included react-bootstrap with npm.

Comment: You'll need higher specificity than the bootstrap classes. You can try using an ID instead of a class. Bootstrap tends to have a lot of `!important` styles also.

Comment: Can you update your code here to show where you've added the `className` to the component

Answer (score 1):

As shown [in the documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/#forms), you can provide a css class (called `className` in React) like that:

```
<Form>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      We'll never share your email with anyone else.
    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

You'll need to import the css file like that:

```
import "example.css";
```

Comment: Already done it, but it just add css code without overriding existing one.

Comment: You can override the existing css. If you do not want the bootstrap styles at all, why don't you create your own form components instead?